# Java: Why is this double variable coming out 0?

Tags: java, double, zero

I am using Java 1.6
    final double check = 3 / 4;
    System.out.println(check);

Console is showing: 0.0

Why is this happening? Shouldn't it come out 0.75?

Comment: **Integer** division then converted to `double`.

Comment: I was just thinking nobody had asked this for a couple of days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make that:

```
double check = 3.0 / 4;
```

and it'll work. You got `0` because `3 / 4` is an integer division, whose value is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Because both are integer hence result will also be integer.

Cast any one into double like this:

```
double check = (double)3 / 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing:

```
3 / 4
```

you are performing an *integer division*, since `3` and `4` are `int` constants, not `double`s. The result is therefore an `int`. But since you are assigning it to a `double`, the *result of the division* will then be promoted to a `double`. But at this point it is too late, since the integer division will have produced 0!

You need to do:

```
3.0 / 4
```

to achieve your desired result, since in this case, `4` will automatically be promoted to a `double`, and the result of the division will also be a `double`.

To be perfectly sure of what happens and if you like symmetry, you can also write:

```
3.0 / 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing integers and assigning the result to double.In java division of two int values always yields an int.
So change the statement `double check = 3 / 4;` to `double check = 3.0 / 4;`